# Непорядок в поле Id таблицы

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

При создании записи в таблице поле Id значения создаются не так как нужно(см. картинку) требуется, что они при создании-удалении шли одно за одной(1,2,3,4 и т.д.), возможно нужно прописать какой-либо тип генерации ключа, либо метод. Используется Hibernate.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Teststud</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>

        <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">false</property>
        <mapping class="DataBase.Tables.Students"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Класс таблицы

```
package DataBase.Tables;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Created by Рабочий on 20.04.2016.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Students {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    private String FirstName;

    @Column(name = "LastName")
    private String LastName;

    @Column(name = "Groupstud")
    private String Group;

    public Students(String FirstName,String LastName,String Group){
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Group = Group;
    }

    public Students(Students stud) {
    }

    public Students() {
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return Group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        Group = group;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если кратко, то нужно придумывать свою методу бездырочной нумерации.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, "*шли одно за одной*" - похоже на требование бизнес-логики, но существует рекомендация - не возлагать на идентификаторы записей в БД никакой логики. Значение первичного ключа в таблице предназначено исключительно для взаимодействия с БД, не следует смешивать эту функциональность с правилами бизнес-логики.

Касательно темы вопроса: стандартный метод генерации значений первичных ключей в MySQL - создание определённого типа поля:

```
ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Тип `BIGINT` - моё личное предпочтение, можно использовать и другие числовые типы. Данное определение поля сообщает СУБД MySQL о том, что если при вставке новой записи значение поля ID не будет явно указано, то автоматически будет взято значение из специально созданного счётчика. Данный счётчик (сиквенс) по умолчанию возвращает числовые значения, начиная с 1, увеличивая значение каждый раз на единицу (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 и т.д.). При этом поле первичного ключа в Вашей `Java`-сущности следует определить следующей `JPA`-аннотацией:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID")
```

Теоретически, такой подход решает Вашу задачу, но на практике идентификаторы могут "выпадать", например, при откате транзакции вставки записи, или при удалении записи из БД.

*PS Вообще, практика строгого порядка нумерации каких-либо документов идёт корнями в бумажный документооборот. Это помогало, например, взглянув на номер последнего созданного документа, сразу определить сколько их было создано, например, за день. В современных информационных системах есть более удобные и надёжные способы получения статистики и отчётности. Этим я хочу сказать, что вероятно, у Вас недостаточно проработана аналитика и постановка задачи.*